# Why Username and password field not displaying in ADFS 3.0 log in page?

Tags: adfs

In ADFS 3.0 login page I am not able to see username and password field.
Only sign in button is showing on log in page. 
Can anybody tell me what are the possibilities because of I am not able to see username and password field?

The login page is shown in attached image.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Change the zoom level of your browser back to 100%.

Also your main Logo should only be `260x35` max or your style sheet will cover over the login fields.

Check the following link for the requirements of the new adfs layouts.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280950.aspx

Comment: @Nicolas As long as the answer is constructive and potentially helpful it's still valuable.